# Changing Views but let the background stay in place

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to let the Background stay in place and only move the Objects in the View with a push effect?
I know that I could let the objects move from out of the view into the view and so on but that isn't really what I was looking for.
Like the effect on the Homescreen with the App-Icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a transparent UIScrollView, have a background behind it. As the subviews of the scroll view scroll, the background won't move.

Comment: Yeah that would only kind of work. I have more than just one consecutive page. Depending on the button clicked I'd want different views to show :(

Comment: Is it possible to set a background to the navigation controller and make the other views transparent?

Comment: Give it a try. You can set any view as transparent.